# How can I get a String from a PersistObjectId in yesod?

Tags: haskell, yesod, persist

From a higher level what I am trying to do is make a post via javascript that includes the ID to an object.

I am passing the 'PlayerId' to a widget that will create the jquery that will post.

```
  tableClickHandlerWidget :: String -> TableId -> PlayerId -> Maybe Int ->  Widget
  tableClickHandlerWidget elemId tid playerId seatId = do
    let seatNumber = if seatId == Nothing
                      then "null"
                      else show  $ fromJust seatId
    let pid = fromPersistToJS $ unKey playerId
    toWidget[julius|
        $(function() {
          $('#{show elemId}').click.post(
            '@{GamingSessionsR}',
            { player: '#{pid}', table: '#{show tid}', seat:'#{seatNumber}' },
            );
        });
        |]
    toWidget[hamlet|something<br/>|]


  fromPersistToJS :: PersistValue -> String
  fromPersistToJS p = do
   let (a) = fromPersistValue p
   case a of
      Left  l -> T.unpack l
      Right  r -> r
```

What i am getting back from fromPersistToJS is always an exception that object id cannot be made into a string.

But the URLs are essentially strings and have IDs inside them; so I am sure this must bepossible.

https://github.com/gdoteof/exodus/ is the whole repo and I am making this post at

https://github.com/gdoteof/exodus/commit/4daa0a25a9f44c69cbdc5c0bb4e8aa4f6433de45

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the answer was very easy.

```
let playerIdAsText = toPathPiece playerId
```

Comment: how to do the reverse ? i.e Text -> playerId , tried fromPathPiece idAsText :: PlayerId didn't work :(

Comment: It will depend on the persistent backend you are using.  If you are using SQL, I think you will need to explicitly convert Text->String->Int

What is your use case for having the ID in a Text in the first place?

Comment: I wanted to convert a input field in a custom form to a key. I finally used Key $ PersistInt64 input_val